# How can I move my button?

Tags: java, 2d, android, collision-detection

I am new to animations in android. I was wondering, is there a way to keep a button moving around the screen, bouncing off the walls, until it gets clicked? I was thinking to do something like this:

```
    while(!clicked){
    //Run code to move button
        }
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
    clicked = true;
        }
    );
```

And to make it random, do something like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
btnCount.animate().xBy(r.nextInt(10)+1).yBy(r.nextInt(10)+1);
```

But that doesn't work, and nothing happens. What is the best way to do this animation?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 500);
        anim.setDuration(300l);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        button.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Please add comments or describe what the code is doing and why you're doing it. Blocks of code are generally not that helpful without explanation.

Comment: But this one is helpful and is self explanatory